# Java exits abruptly on a Windows 11 VM (host is M1 Mac)

Tags: java, maven, virtual-machine, apple-m1, parallels

I'm having a very odd issue with Java exiting abruptly and randomly.

I have a **Macbook with M1 system** (2021 model), with 32GB RAM. I'm running a Windows 11 **(ARM64 Insider Preview)** VM with **Parallels**. I have 16GB of RAM allocated for the VM, and 6 cores. I have **Liberica JDK 8 (full with JavaFX)** installed both on the host and the VM. I'm developing a multi-module Maven project, same project on both the host side and the VM side (the project depends on some Windows side things for some tasks, which is the reason I'm running the Windows VM on the side).

Output from `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)
```

I've also tried with Azul JDK and had the same issue with it.

On the host side everything works as it should. Maven and Java commands both run successfully with no interruption or issues. On the Windows VM side however, it seems that Java just randomly exits with no error logs or anything really. I noticed it just hangs for a few seconds, and then just exits abruptly. I noticed that it may happen while running a Maven command, or for example running a `.jar` package with `java -jar`. Here's a picture of what it looks like (same happens on the picture above though):

[image: Maven command exits randomly here]

A couple weeks back I had no issues at all. But then I had to reinstall Parallels and the VM (reinstalled the whole W11 OS), and suddenly these issues started occurring. I've tried adding `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to see if it's a `OutOfMemoryError`, but it did not seem to have any results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not post command-line text as screen shot. That makes it really hard to read. Copy and paste it instead as text into your question. If a Java VM process crashes it usually creates a dump log in the the current directory, check if something like this exists.

Comment: @Robert sorry about that, I'll edit and copy paste logs in text when I run into this issue again. In my case there is no any dump logs appearing in the current directory.

Comment: Maybe as a hint to see if its related to memory: You can have a look at VisualVM (https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) to monitor your memory consumption of your Java application during execution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MarcelGohsen! [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/cuqcakH.png) a link to an image from the monitoring view from a crashed run.

Comment: @F4irline Based on these results I would not suspect problems regarding memory. You configured 4GB of Heap Space and you still have plenty of headroom.

Comment: @MarcelGohsen yep, that's what I thought as well. Such a weird issue, probably going to reinstall Parallels and the VM once more at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this issue: I was able to resolve this issue by installing the Windows 11 VM into Parallels from an image downloaded from [UUP Dump](https://uupdump.net/).

I tried reinstalling the VM downloaded from the Microsoft's Insider Preview page, but the issue still persisted and nothing seemed to be able to fix it. Java still exited randomly pretty frequently.

I downloaded the latest Windows 11 image from UUP Dump and installed that one instead. Installed the exact same versions of Maven, Java, Groovy etc. and surprisingly, the issue vanished. I've been able to run Java on my VM for a day now without issues, whereas with the image downloaded from Microsoft I was able to reproduce the issue pretty much within minutes after configuring my environment and cloning the Git repo of the project I'm developing.

Answer (score 0):

A *lot* improved for me after switching to [ARM64 Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download) (Microsoft's was first one I found, there may be others).

Some background: not sure if I had *exactly* the same issue, but vscode compiling and code checking was slow and unreliable, and my Mendix Java application kept crashing or not even starting. Since that uses Java 11, that's what I installed the ARM64 version of. This is in Windows 11 ARM, from Microsoft's Preview page, updated (hang the first try, but worked the second).